# How to input a function in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can do a hack like this:

```
 function exec(fn){
     setInterval(fn,0);
 }

 exec("newfn()");
```

But looking for a cleaner way.

Comment: Why not `setInterval(newfn,0);` ? But... `0` ?

Comment: if you're going to pass a function, pass a reference, not the name.

Comment: @zzzzBov Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Zee: See adeneo's comment.

Comment: @FelixKling So you're saying adeneo's comment is the cleanest way?

Comment: Passing a function reference is much cleaner than passing a string. It's also easier to debug.

Comment: Ok, but using `setInterval` is the cleanest way? @adeneo @FelixKling

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. If you want to execute a function repeatedly, then you have to use `setInterval` (although a timeout of `0` doesn't make sense then). If you simply what to execute a function, put `()` after the reference. E.g. `fn();`. But if that's all that `exec` does, then you can directly write `newfn()`. Since you haven't provided any context for your problem, it's not clear to me what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @FelixKling `How to input a function in a function that will exec that function` <- that's what i want to do.  Is using setInterval the only way to exec the function when it is passed as a fn parameter?

Comment: As I said, no. Just put `()` after the function reference: `function exec(fn) { fn(); }`. And again, while you can absolutely do this, I don't see any advantage of `exec(foo)` over `foo()`.

Comment: @FelixKling Then please answer the question and I will give the best answer b/c that's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, the best way to pass a function to another function is to pass a **reference** to it, not a string containing its name.

Example:

```
function foo() {
  console.log('Inside foo');
}

exec(foo);
```

To execute the function inside exec, you just have to put `()` after the function reference:

```
function exec(fn) { 
  fn(); 
}
```

But while you can absolutely do this, I don't see any advantage of using `exec(foo)` over `foo()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
function exec(fn){
     window[fn]();
}
exec("newfn");
```

provided that functions are in global scope.

Comment: that's a pretty big pre-condition which will often not be the case

Comment: @sahbeewah, well it won't work even if `setTimeout(foo,0)` is done and foo is not a function in global scope

Comment: `newfn()` is another function in global scope

Comment: @AmitJoki: Yes it will, `foo` just has to be in scope, it doesn't have to be global.

Comment: No, since `fn` is a string.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes. I'm saying is this right? `[fn]();`

Comment: Nope, that will create an array and try to treat the array as a function.

Answer (score 0):

simply pass function name:

```
function exec(fn){
   setInterval(fn,0);
}
exec(newfn);
```